# How to get index of ComboBox?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So i've a class "mainpercentage.m", and I want one variable in that class assume a value of ComboBox index. I've tried method "indexOfSelectedItem", but I can not understand the syntax.
Thank's for help!

```
Mainpercentage.m:

@implementation MainPercentage
- (IBAction)SetPercentage:(id)sender {
/*

Here I want get index of my ComboBox

*/
    if (1==1) {
        [pryam setIntValue:40]; //pryam- FormCell
        [razb setIntValue:30];
        [estestv setIntValue:30];
    }

}

- (IBAction)GetKon:(id)sender {

}
@end

Mainpercentage.h:
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MainPercentage : NSObject {
    IBOutlet id estestv;
    IBOutlet id pryam;
    IBOutlet id razb;
}
- (IBAction)SetPercentage:(id)sender;
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (NSInteger)indexOfSelectedItem
```

So if you have an `NSComboBox`, let's call it `myCombo`, you would say this:

```
NSInteger indexInteger = [myCombo indexOfSelectedItem];
```

Now indexInteger is an `NSInteger` whose value is the index.

Comment: MMM, i've named my ComboBox "myCombo", rewrited Class Files, and pasted your code into my method, but it says: "myCombo is undeclared". Where should I declare it? Thanks.

Comment: It would help to see what you are doing. Can you post your method for us to see please. Cheers

Comment: @implementation MainPercentage
- (IBAction)SetPercentage:(id)sender {
 if (1==1) {
  [pryam setIntValue:40]; //pryam - FormCell
  [razb setIntValue:30];  //razb - FormCell
  [estestv setIntValue:30]; //estestv - FormCell
 }
    
}

@end

Comment: place it as an IBOutlet in your Mainpercentage.h:, the same as you have done for the other outlets. Also you should edit your question, to show the code and not put it as an answer. It will confused people.

Comment: Thank's. Sorry, i'm just a newbie here and in XCode. Really thank you for help.

Comment: I understand:-). I also think it maybe worth you looking at core data, which may suit what you are trying to do and take a lot of the coding out of your hands. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html and tutorials http://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Core+Data+tutorial&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=A4yETYOIN8jDhAea9-y_BA